# How to make new object of a class from a string?

Tags: java, object

Let say I have a variable containing some text. So how would I do:

```
Object obj=new [text];
```

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: New object of which class? What does the string have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really get your question exactly.

But you can create a new object of `String` class just like this:

```
new String("some text");
```

If you want to cast it to `Object` class then you can do that like this:

```
Object obj = (Object) new String("some text");  //or
Object obj = (Object) "some text";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not very idiomatic java; for example, classes have constructors, and you'd have to know what kind of constructor it has to do this.

**IF** you know that ALL of the following are true:

1. The stated class exists and is on the classpath.
2. The class name you have is fully qualified; imports do not count here, so you have `com.foo.pkgname.ClassName`, not `ClassName` combined with `import com.foo.pkgname.*`
3. Said class is not abstract, and an actual class (not an interface or enum or whatnot).
4. Said class has a constructor with no arguments. Note that if a class has no constructors listed at all, the compiler injects `public ClassName() {super();}` automatically.

then, and only then:

```
Class<?> stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
Object instanceOfString = stringClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
String ex = (String) instanceOfString; // will work!
```

will do the job, though a whole bunch of exceptions waft out because so much can go wrong here (the class doesn't exist; the class isn't accessible; the class doesn't have a no-args constructor in the first place; the class is abstract; it's not a class but an interface; the call went though but the constructor itself threw an exception).

NB: You can shortcut `stringClass.getConstructor().newInstance()` to just `stringClass.newInstance()` - but **don't do that** - this method is deprecated at this point (might not yet be if you're on an older version, but the reasons for its deprecation are solid and count for all versions), and the exception behaviour of that method is bizarre. Use this longer form.